# jQuery height() in a condition conflicts somehow

Tags: jquery, height, alert

I have problems with my condition that checks if some element is higher than 29. This is my code:

```
jQuery('.somepath a span.lines').each(function() {
    var spanHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    alert(spanHeight);
    if(spanHeight > 29) {
        alert('test');  
    }
});
```

Alerts: 22, 22, 22, 22, 44, test (so that works fine)

When I delete the first alert() its not working anymore, so alert('test'); isnt executed anymore:

```
jQuery('.somepath a span.lines').each(function() {
    var spanHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    if(spanHeight > 29) {
        alert('test');  
    }
});
```

I cant understand whats going wrong here.. I tried a lot of things but I cant get it work.

Does anyone see or know the problem? parseInt() isnt the solution also..

Comment: can you make a simple jsfiddle with some html to show us what's going on?

Comment: Don't use alert for debugging, try it with `console.log()`

Comment: Probably your first code sample is benefiting from the delay caused by each `alert()`. It's impossible to know for sure or how without seeing more of your code.

Comment: @blazemonger That could be possible.. But this is the last row of Javascript in my application so I cant imagine that but I will check that right now...

Comment: @tkone this code is part of a big application. Im gonne check first the comment of blazemonger

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as given. You'll have to show us a complete working example before we can tease out the real cause of your problem.

Comment: @ArekvanSchayk does the console show any errors after deleting the alert?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is executed after the DOM is fully loaded? Try to wrap it into jQuery(document).ready(), I think that Blazemonger  is right. The alert causes your javascript to pause just long enough to let the DOM load.

Comment: Im using css less in my application (the .less files are rendered by javascript on my dev environment). So the above code is checking its height when there isnt css active yet, so there isnt a second row in my span because the css-less page causes a single line display.

Answer (score 0):

Make span  `display: inline-block;` it will work -

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XKgTk/)

```
<span class="lines" style="height: 30px; display: inline-block;">asdf sd fsda</span>​

$('span.lines').each(function() {
    var spanHeight = $(this).height();
    if(spanHeight > 29) {
        alert('test');  
    }
});​
```

Comment: When I remove the `style` attribute with your fixed height and display inline block its still working so this cant be the right solution.

Comment: @ArekvanSchayk it doesn't work when you remove style attribute - http://jsfiddle.net/XKgTk/1/

Comment: @ArekvanSchayk In fact it doesn't work if you remove display: inline-block property